Problema al intentar cambiar una imagen
Mi problema es este:
<div id="leftSection">
    <button id="playPauseBtn"></button>
    <audio id="audioPlayer" src="playerservices.streamtheworld.com/api/livestream-redirect/…">
    <div id="announcerSection">
        <img id="announcerImage" src="https://page-images.websim.ai/DJ%20John%20Doe_1024x1024xf0bTtkho6qDwyjqxZx910b289de08b8.jpg" >
        <span id="announcer">DJ John</span>
    </div>
</div>

en la linea de img cuando intento colocar una imagen guardada en una carpeta no me deja o sea no aparece. solamente puedo usar
https://page-images.websim.ai/DJ%20John%20Doe_1024x1024xf0bTtkho6qDwyjqxZx910b289de08b8.jpg**


no sé porque no me ha aparecido la linea de código intentaré ponerla por aquí... 




DJ John



No estoy seguro si entiendes lo que haces o si te he entenido bien. Si intentas arrastrar una imagen de una carpeta a un editor de HTML normalmente no sucede nada, como mucho te pondria la ruta de la imagen, pero no parece ser el caso.  El atributo src= espera una ruta hacia una imagen, no una imagen en sí.

Y tu línea de código no ha aparecido porque no sabes usar tampoco el editor de esta web.  Si pulsas sobre [edit] verás como te lo he reformateado para que aparezca mejor.

es lo que he hecho lo que pasa es que no sé porqué solo me toma imágenes que tengan esta característica y es https o http, cuando le doy la dirección de por ejemplo src="images/logo.png" no la carga aunque me muestra que si está en la carpeta señalada. No sé si me he explicado bien.

Masterguru gracias es que no pregunto nunca sino que cuadno busco algo ya alguien lo ha solucionado

Si quieres usar imágenes de tu disco será porque tienes la web corriendo en el mismo ordenador, sino no te funcionará.  Para ello debes poner file:// y despues toda la ruta hasta la imagen, como así: src="file:///home/cuenta/images/logo.png"... si estás en windows ni idea, pero tienes un truco que es facil de hacer, que es arrastrar la imagen a un navegador y fijarte lo que pone en el campo de URL que hay arriba, y veras que empieza por file:// y luego el resto de la ruta correcta hacia la imagen. Pones el cursor alli y copias todo eso y lo pegas en el src= y yasta.

Y si tu web no está en tu mismo ordenador entonces debes subir la imagen a tu servidor web y usar http o https con su ruta absoluta o bien con una ruta relativa como images/logo.png pero siempre subiendo primero la imagen a tu servidor web y colocándola en esa carpeta.

Muchas gracias ya me funciona. Pero mi pregunta es porque en otro archivos pongo la dirección y si me funciona y en este código no :(

No se a que te refieres con "otros archivos" ni como lo has solucionado finalmente. Si esos otros archivos han sido subidos a otros servidores o los coges de otras webs entonces iran con el http(s) por delante, pero si no los subes y solo quieres usarlos desde tu ordenador entonces necesitas usar el file:// para llegar a ellos de forma local (piensa que eso solo lo verás tu, nadie más, pues los file:// solo estan en tu máquina).

Te entiendo. Perdona que no sepa explicarme mejor. Cuando digo otros archivos me refiero a otros archivos html que sólo coloco la dirección de la carpeta donde está el archivo y ya está lo carga en la vista local. No hace falta ponerle file /// ni nada de eso, solo pongo por ejemplo images/logo.png y me lo carga en vista local como he dicho. Pero con tu ayuda ya lo he solucionado. Muchas gracias.

Pues fijate bien si las rutas coinciden con las otras imágenes que tienes, es decir, te vas a la carpeta donde haya alguna imagen que sí puedas ver aunque esté escrita así: images/imagen.png y la arrastras al navegador, y comparas las rutas, y seguramente son distintas y por eso no te funciona.  Ese tipo de rutas, que se llaman relativas, tambien dependen de la carpeta o ruta desde la cual estes abriendo el HTML, pues quizas es distinta a otro HTML donde si aparecen.

una pregunta. Cómo hago para dar por cerrado este tema y si hay que darte alguna estrella o algo. Es que en verdad no sé cómo va el asunto aquí.

Léete el [tour] pero en este caso la pregunta quedará pendiente de respuesta, pues solo te he ayudado con comentarios sin escribir una respuesta (y me da pereza hacerlo).  Con un poco de suerte alguien la cerrará y te apuntará a alguna pregunta similar con una respuesta más concisa, o bien, simplemente elimina esta pregunta (antes guarda todo lo que te he dicho para tenerlo de referencia).  Las estrillitas me dan igual, la verdad, pero gracias.

O bien tu mismo puedes escribir una respuesta explicando lo que te ha funcionado, y en 24 horas te dejarán valorarla (aunque no te dará puntos, pero tendrá una respuesta marcada como correcta para el siguiente que llegue)

Fijate en la ruta de archivo voy a citar a W3schools en éste siguiente párrafo.

Rutas de archivo web absolutas:
Consisten en la URL completa de un archivo. EJ:"https:// dominio web / ruta de archivo"
Rutas de archivo relativas:
Es la ubicación del archivo ubicado en la carpeta donde está archivada el código También cuenta si está dentro de una carpeta dentro de la misma carpeta. EJ: "ruta de archivo" Coloca una / detras si la imagen está en la raíz de la web o arriba o ../ sí está a nivel arriba

Utiliza las rutas de archivo absolutas si las imágenes no son de tú dominio, y las relativas si son de tu dominio
